# How to layout UI elements in better way programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm laying out user interface programmatically like the code below. Is there any better way to do this programmatically? For example using design patterns or something that I'm not even aware of that it exists.
Reason I'm searching for better way is that when I have to change the UI design or layout it feels really ugly and messy.

```
- (void) loadView
{
    [super loadVIew];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.title = @"ペットショップ";

    float y = 44;
    float x = 0;
    float width = self.view.frame.size.width;
    float height = width * .6;

    if (!topPictureView_) {
        topPictureView_ = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
        topPictureView_.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        topPictureView_.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"info_bg"];
        topPictureView_.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        [self.view addSubview:topPictureView_];
        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:topPictureView_];
    }

    y+=height-35;
    height = 35;

    if (!lblBranchName_) {
        lblBranchName_ = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height  )];
        lblBranchName_.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:.3 alpha:1];
        lblBranchName_.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.8 alpha:.7];
        lblBranchName_.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        lblBranchName_.text = @"ペットショップ KOMATSU";
        lblBranchName_.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:17];
        [self.view addSubview:lblBranchName_];
    }

    y+=height;
    height = 45*4;

    y+=5;

    height = 50;

    float col = self.view.frame.size.width/2;
    float margin = 5;

    btn11_ = [self createButtonWithFrame:CGRectMake(margin, y, col-margin*1.5, height) title:@"11" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu"]];
    btn12_ = [self createButtonWithFrame:CGRectMake(col+margin/2, y, col-margin*1.5, height) title:@"12" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"order"]];
    y+= height+margin;

    btn21_ = [self createButtonWithFrame:CGRectMake(margin, y, col-margin*1.5, height) title:@"21" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"order"]];
    btn22_ = [self createButtonWithFrame:CGRectMake(col+margin/2, y, col-margin*1.5, height) title:@"22" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map"]];

    y+= height+margin;

    btnChat = [self createButtonWithFrame:CGRectMake(margin, y, col*2-margin*2, height) title:@"Chat" image:nil];


    y+=height+margin;
    height = self.view.frame.size.height-y;

    if (!eventBanner_) {
        eventBanner_ = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height )];
        eventBanner_.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"banner"];
        [self.view addSubview:eventBanner_];
    }
}
- (UIButton *) createButtonWithFrame:(CGRect) frame title:(NSString *)title image:(UIImage *) image {
    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [btn setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [[btn layer]setBorderWidth:1.0f  ];
    [[btn layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor grayColor].CGColor];
    [[btn layer] setCornerRadius:10.0f];
    btn.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
    return btn;
}
```

Comment: Read up about AutoLayout, also why not try Interface Builder. Also, don't call [super loadView] from loadView. "You can override this method in order to create your views manually. If you choose to do so, assign the root view of your view hierarchy to the view property. The views you create should be unique instances and should not be shared with any other view controller object. Your custom implementation of this method should not call super."

Comment: I'm told not to use IB. This is how the company that I'm working in doing it right now. I tried not to call `[super loadView]` then my `-(void) loadView` got called infinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use [NSLayoutContraint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html). It makes for much more cleaner and portable code for you UI design. If you are new to it, Ray Wenderlish offers a nice two part [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2).

Comment: Is it available in iOS 5?

Comment: yup.. in fact that's where it was introduced.. b/c that's when you started getting different form factors (ie screens with different resolutions etc).. that's why it became necessary to have a way to describe where ui elements appeared on the screen without being screen size/resolution dependent.. something similar to how android describes its layout

Comment: @DulguunLst Just updated my answer with an easy to follow tutorial.. enjoy :)

Comment: Autolayout came in iOS _6_.

Comment: @StephenDarlington dang that's true.. my bad

Comment: ahh i want to drop the support of iOS 5 really bad lol. But I guess this isn't happening any time soon